# Argumenets not executing when doing get_posts()

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to utilise AJAX for pagination. However, my get_posts() call doesn't seem to be finding any results from my custom taxonomy `Case Studies`.

- `Case Studies` has **10 posts** in total.
- 5 posts are displayed by default, then on `Load more` click, 5 more will appear.
- The issue lies with the `ajax_handler()` - I'm unsure where my argument is going wrong. I have tried `query_posts` and `get_posts()`.

```js
jQuery(function($){

    $('#loadmore').click(function(){

        var column_width = $(this).data('column-width');
        var max_num_pages = $(this).data('max-num-pages');
        var post_type = $(this).data('type');

        var button = $(this),
          data = {
            action:'loadmore',
            query: loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            page : loadmore_params.current_page,
            security : loadmore_params.security,
            columns : column_width,
            max_num_pages : max_num_pages,
            post_type : post_type
          };  

        $.ajax({
            url : loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // ajax handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',

            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); 
            },

            // return data on succesful callback ...
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    button.text( 'Load More' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    // where to insert new posts...
                    $('.case-studies-container').find('.case-card').last().after( data );

                    // if it's the last page in the query, remove the button
                    // if ( loadmore_params.current_page == max_num_pages )
                    //     button.remove(); 

                     console.log(data);

                } else {
                    // remove the button if there's no more content to load
                    button.remove(); 
                }
            },

            error : function(error){ 
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<?php
function ajax_handler(){

  check_ajax_referer('load_more', 'security');
 
  // prepare our arguments for the query
  $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true ); 
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
  $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $args['max_num_pages'] = $_POST['max_num_pages'];

  $posts = query_posts( $args );

  var_dump($posts);

  if( have_posts() ) :

    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
        
    // get template part here

    endwhile;
  endif;

  die;
}
?>
```

- `var_dump($posts)` returns `array(0) {}`
- `var_dump($args)` returns nothing, not even the post id.

Unsure what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What is **$_POST['query']**? which argument  is there?

Comment: How do you call your function ajax_handler?

Comment: @Kvasir - I've updated my question to show load-more.js where the ajax call is made.

Comment: Did the console show any errors? Are you sure your AJAX call was actually successful? Because if yes, then the `$_POST['query']` in your `ajax_handler()` wouldn't be empty, unless it's empty when it's localized.